# Automate ssh operation in Cygwin Perl

Tags: perl, ssh, cygwin

I'm using Perl 5.14.2 in Cygwin x86, i want to automate the download of config file of a Cisco device via ssh connection.
To establish ssh connection i tried with two different perl modules, Net::Telnet and Net::Appliance::Session, but i obtained the same result:

```
    [   0.020658] pr finding prompt
    [   0.030873] tr creating Net::Telnet wrapper for ssh
    [   0.033997] tr connecting with:  ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownH
    ostsFile=/dev/null -o CheckHostIP=no -l user x.x.x.x
    [   0.176672] du   SEEN:
    usage: ssh [-1246AaCfghkNnqsTtVvXxY] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
           [-D port] [-e escape_char] [-F configfile] [-i identity_file]
           [-L port:host:hostport] [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-o option]
           [-p port] [-R port:ho
    [   0.204828] ph  reading phrasebook /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14/Net/CLI/Inter
    act/phrasebook/cisco/pb
    [   0.206988] ph  reading phrasebook /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14/Net/CLI/Inter
    act/phrasebook/cisco/ios/pb
    [   0.208445] ph   storing prompt generic
    [   0.218928] ph   storing prompt basic
    [   0.219794] ph   storing prompt privileged
    [   0.220544] ph   storing prompt configure
    [   0.221287] ph   storing prompt user
    [   0.222011] ph   storing prompt pass
```

Seems that Cygwin ignore the parameters that perl modules passed to ssh command.
This is my code which use Net::Appliance::Session:

```
     use strict;
     use Net::Appliance::Session;

     my $host="x.x.x.x";

     my $user="user";
     my $pass="pass";

     my $server="x.x.x.x";
     my $fileName="file";


     my $ssh = Net::Appliance::Session->new({
                                             personality => 'ios',
                                             transport => 'SSH',
                                             host => $host
                                           });

     $ssh->set_global_log_at('debug');

     $ssh->connect({username => $user, password => $pass});

     #enable password is the same
     $ssh->begin_privileged({ password => $pass });

     print $ssh->cmd("copy system:/running-config tftp://$server/$fileName");
```

Instead the code that use Net::Telnet is the same that is belown in this page at examples's section:
http://search.cpan.org/~jrogers/Net-Telnet-3.04/lib/Net/Telnet.pm

I tried in Window 7 and in Windows XP also.
What can be the problem?

Comment: You should consider using keys, instead of passwords for authentication. If it is really just a copy/download, you should give some consideration to using rsync.

Comment: Maybe you will get some ideas from the next two links: https://metacpan.org/pod/release/OLIVER/Net-Appliance-Session-2.111080/lib/Net/Appliance/Session/Cookbook/Intro.pod and https://metacpan.org/pod/release/OLIVER/Net-Appliance-Session-1.36/lib/Net/Appliance/Session/Cookbook/Recipe02.pod

Comment: This is a test, then i include this code in a existing software,  i will condiser using keys in the future. I cannot use rsync, i must do the download in Perl

Comment: Thanks, now i look at these links

Comment: i found nothing can help me in these links